# Bad Assignment (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Am new to JavaScript and the DOM, so am trying to write a program that displays a text once you click a button and changes the text once you click the button again. Though the program runs as expected but I get a **Bad Assignment** warning because I assigned a function to another function so am trying to know if it isn't proper to do so and if there is a better way of doing it. Here's the code below, at the **thirdClick()** function that's where I did the assignment.

```
const body = document.body;
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');


const firstClick = function() {
    const h1 = document.querySelector('#h1');
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        h1.innerText = 'I Am Injected Into This Page  by JavaScript , Click the Button Again and see ';
        body.append(h1);
        secondClick();
    });
};


const secondClick = function() {
    const h2 = document.querySelector('#h1');
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        h2.innerText = 'Am also injected into this page by JavaScript cool right ';
        body.append(h2);
        thirdClick();
    });
};


const thirdClick = function() {
    if (secondClick()) {
        secondClick() = firstClick();
    }
    else {
        firstClick();
    }
};

firstClick();
```

Comment: A button can have multiple event listeners.  Adding a new one doesn't remove what was already there.  So when you call firstClick or secondClick multiple times, you are adding more event listeners to the button, which will all execute when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign values to variables and properties of objects.

```
const foo = 1;
const bar = {};
bar.baz = 2;
```

You can't assign a value to the result of calling a function:

```
alert("Hello, world!") = 3; // Nonsense!
```

… because it isn't designed to be something you can store data in.

---

If you want to track clicks and do different things depending on how many there were, then assign functions to a *variable* that you reference, or just keep a count.

```js
function one() {
  document.body.style.background = 'blue';
}

function two() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>Hello, world</p>");
}

function three() {
  document.body.style.background = 'yellow';
}

const functions = [one, two, three];
let nextFunction = 0;

function clickHandler() {
  const f = functions[nextFunction];
  if (f) f();
  nextFunction++;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks alot you really understood me, I wasn't trying to track how many times the button was clicked, I wanted a text to be displayed on the first click and an entirely different text to be displayed on the second click